# How can I display multiple plots in one window in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

```
function res = plot2features(tset, f1, f2)
% Plots tset samples on a 2-dimensional diagram
%   using features f1 and f2
% tset - training set; the first column contains class label
% f1 - index of the first feature (mapped to horizontal axis)
% f2 - index of the second feature (mapped to vertical axis)
% 
% res - matrix containing values of f1 and f2 features

    % plotting parameters for different classes
    %   restriction to 8 classes seems reasonable
    pattern(1,:) = 'ks';
    pattern(2,:) = 'rd';
    pattern(3,:) = 'mv';
    pattern(4,:) = 'b^';
    pattern(5,:) = 'gs';
    pattern(6,:) = 'md';
    pattern(7,:) = 'mv';
    pattern(8,:) = 'g^';

    res = tset(:, [f1, f2]);

    % extraction of all unique labels used in tset
    labels = unique(tset(:,1));

    % create diagram and switch to content preserving mode
    figure;
    hold on;
    for i=1:size(labels,1)
        idx = tset(:,1) == labels(i);
        plot(res(idx,1), res(idx,2), pattern(i,:));
    end
    hold off;
end
```

I have written this function and I want to show multiple `plot2featutes()` in one widow in MATLAB.

I tried the following,

```
subplot(2,2,1);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,2);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,3);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,4);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
```

That doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you create a new figure in your `plot2features` function which, *surprise surprise*, creates a new figure and the plotting is done in the new figure

Comment: Do note create a new `figure` inside `plot2features`. Modify it to take an axis handle as input, and give that as the `'Parent'` argument for the plot command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem is with the line `figure;` in your function. Without an argument, `figure` creates a new figure and then switches focus to that figure. Your function should look more like this:

```
function res = plot2features(tset, f1, f2)
% Plots tset samples on a 2-dimensional diagram
%   using features f1 and f2
% tset - training set; the first column contains class label
% f1 - index of the first feature (mapped to horizontal axis)
% f2 - index of the second feature (mapped to vertical axis)
% 
% res - matrix containing values of f1 and f2 features

    % plotting parameters for different classes
    %   restriction to 8 classes seems reasonable
    pattern = {'ks'; 'rd'; 'mv'; 'b^'; 'gs'; 'md'; 'mv'; 'g^'};

    res = tset(:, [f1, f2]);

    % extraction of all unique labels used in tset
    labels = unique(tset(:,1));

    % create diagram and switch to content preserving mode
    for ii = 1:size(labels,1)
        if ii == 1
            hold off
        else
            hold on
        end
        idx = tset(:,1) == labels(ii);
        plot(res(idx,1), res(idx,2), pattern{ii});
    end
    hold off;
end
```

I made three changes to your code:

- I removed `figure` and replaced it with a test that turns `hold off` on the first pass so that a new axis is created and subsequent plots are then drawn inside those axes.
- I changed your index from the built-in `i` (which is sqrt(-1)) to `ii` to avoid ambiguity
- I changed `pattern` to a cell array for no reason other than my own personal aesthetics.

Call like this:

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,2);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,3);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
subplot(2,2,4);plot2features(train, 2, 3);
```